# Notices on online contributions pages

Tags: contribution-page

After upgrading CiviCRM from 5.20 to 5.44.0 we started getting lots of notice errors on screen specially on front end online pages, is that something we need to worry about? We did some QA by submitting Donation, Membership and Event registration everything seems to be working as expected.

```
Notice: Undefined index: trackingFields in include() (line 5 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%6E/6ED/6ED627C5%%TrackingFields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: islifetime in include() (line 93 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: ispricelifetime in include() (line 93 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_quick_config in include() (line 5 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: renewal_mode in include() (line 10 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: membershipBlock in include() (line 22 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: membershipBlock in include() (line 26 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: help_pre in include() (line 29 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FA/FA7/FA71A514%%PriceSet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: help_post in include() (line 65 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FA/FA7/FA71A514%%PriceSet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: auto_renew_membership_field in include() (line 123 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FA/FA7/FA71A514%%PriceSet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: help_pre in include() (line 29 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FA/FA7/FA71A514%%PriceSet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: help_post in include() (line 117 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FA/FA7/FA71A514%%PriceSet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: auto_renew_membership_field in include() (line 123 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%FA/FA7/FA71A514%%PriceSet.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: noCalcValueDisplay in include() (line 6 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%E1/E1B/E1B56AD0%%Calculate.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: autoRenewOption in include() (line 79 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: membershipBlock in include() (line 154 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: membershipBlock in include() (line 179 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%0B/0BB/0BBEE922%%MembershipBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_pledge_payment in include() (line 138 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_pledge_interval in include() (line 154 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: start_date_editable in include() (line 163 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: start_date in include() (line 174 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: start_date_display in include() (line 176 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: pcpSupporterText in include() (line 221 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: help_pre in include() (line 6 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%70/70E/70E79F81%%Block.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: phone_ext-3-1 in include() (line 124 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: html_type in include() (line 134 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: html_type in include() (line 150 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: options_per_line in include() (line 63 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_datetime_field in include() (line 108 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: html_type in include() (line 134 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: html_type in include() (line 150 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%5C/5C2/5C26BC2B%%Fields.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: field in include() (line 10 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%70/70E/70E79F81%%Block.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: help_post in include() (line 10 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%70/70E/70E79F81%%Block.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: submittedOnBehalfInfo in include() (line 123 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%B0/B02/B02188B6%%OnBehalfOf.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: submittedOnBehalf in include() (line 126 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%B0/B02/B02188B6%%OnBehalfOf.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: showCMS in include() (line 5 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%98/98F/98F6DF1D%%CMSUser.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: preview in include() (line 33 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: preview in include() (line 37 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: thumbnail in include() (line 39 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: image in include() (line 39 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: preview in include() (line 39 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: membershipBlock in include() (line 53 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%DF/DF4/DF4B6A64%%PremiumBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: honoreeProfileFields in include() (line 266 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: customPre in include() (line 298 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: isHonor in include() (line 304 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: is_pay_later in include() (line 361 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: description in include() (line 31 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%2F/2F3/2F376CCE%%BillingBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: description in include() (line 31 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%2F/2F3/2F376CCE%%BillingBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: description in include() (line 31 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%2F/2F3/2F376CCE%%BillingBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: description in include() (line 31 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%2F/2F3/2F376CCE%%BillingBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: profileAddressFields in include() (line 47 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%2F/2F3/2F376CCE%%BillingBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: profileAddressFields in include() (line 78 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%2F/2F3/2F376CCE%%BillingBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: event in include() (line 50 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%51/516/51624B60%%paymentBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: urlPathVar in include() (line 86 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%51/516/51624B60%%paymentBlock.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: customPost in include() (line 383 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: bank_account_number in include() (line 389 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: isCaptcha in include() (line 398 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: footer_text in include() (line 412 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: isHonor in include() (line 420 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: allowAutoRenewMembership in include() (line 447 of /Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/%%3D/3D1/3D13F2BA%%Main.tpl.php).
```

Comment: clean up directory `/Users/sportskida/Sites/drupal7/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_GB/*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing you need to worry about those php notices from Smarty, Can you check if you have debugging enabled? If so by turning off debugging the notices should disappear.

To turn off debugging you will need to navigate to CiviCRM >> Administer >> System Settings >> Debugging and Error Handling. Find for 'Enable Debugging' option on the form, choose 'No' and save it.

HTH

Pradeep